# Review queue "Late answers" - flag when choice was "recommend deletion"?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging, review

When reviewing "Late answers", many of them are not actually answers but comments, other questions and so on (as you can select when saying "recommend deletion").

If I choose to recommend deletion because of this, should I flag the post as "not an answer" as well? Does this place them in some other queue I cannot access yet and get them deleted faster?

Comment: Flag as not an answer will get fastest deletion, as long as a mod is online.